# How do I skip the Daydream Tutorial

Tags: android, daydream

As the question implies how can I do as little setup to get to the Daydream home screen.

I have 26 phones to set up with a 360 Video player, easy enough, but if the user clicks the Home button on the Daydream controller it goes to the Tutorial instead of a Home Screen.

Can I edit a config file via adb to skip it?

Comment: If you could, that would require rooted devices

Comment: Ideally not being rooted since the time to flash 26 Pixel's would negate any time savings skipping the Daydream tutorial.

Comment: Well, assuming said config file existed, I would like to think it's in a SharedPreferences file within the apps private data directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my own answer by digging into the .ConfigService config, and it does require root or a userdebug build of Android to accomplish this.

Edit the prefs file: `/data/data/com.google.vr.vrcore/shared_prefs/VrCoreSettings.xml`
and change `"DaydreamSetupComplete"` to `"True"`

You'll probably want to make a copy of the file as a tmp to copy back.

Then, edit the VR welcome required flag in the vr.vrcore:

```
shell am startservice \
      -n com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigService \
      -a com.google.android.gms.config.OVERRIDE \
      --es __package__ com.google.vr.vrcore \
      --es __namespace__ configns:p4 \
      --es vr_welcome_required false
```

Doing the above also circumvents the step in the initial Daydream setup to put in a payment method which on production builds of Oreo is an roadblock to complete setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can skip the entire tutorial via adb, but the majority of the tutorial can be skipped by pressing the skip button, visible if you look down once the tutorial starts.